# How to query my model in Laravel with relationships using query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have three models:

- User
- Image
- Post

and their relationship is:

- User hasMany Image,
- Image belongsTo User,
- User hasMany Post,
- Post belongsTo User,

How can I query out the relationship using **query builder** until I have the data below?

````
user_name: name,
image: [
  {
    ... 
  },
  {
   ...
  }
],
post: [
  {
   ...
  },
  {
   ...
  }
]```
````

Comment: why dont u use eloquent?

Comment: @TsaiKoga eloquent is great but when it comes to a lot of data, it is really slow even when using eager loading the relationship

Comment: i don't thinks in query builder allow relationship

Comment: if you use query builder then you don't need make relationship in model

Comment: @KamleshPaul yea...so its there anyway such as joining the table or some sort? because the performance of eloquent when it comes to a lot of data

Comment: @EmtiazZahid then how can I query out the data to achieve the output?

Comment: @RezuanKassim u r right, eloquent is slower than query builder. However,  a lot of datas will still make your app slow. It is something wrong with your design, u need to  ensure do u really need all of those datas.

Comment: @TsaiKoga yea..but it is hard to revamp the design because this is a team project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
$user = User::find(1);

$images = $user->images // images is function name as u added in relationship

$posts = $user->posts // posts is function name as u added in relationship


$response = [
'user_name' => $user->name,
'images' => $images,
'posts' => $posts,
];

return response($response);
```

---

you can use also

```php
$user = User::with(['images','posts'])->find(1);
```

Comment: is there another way rather than using Eloquent? because Eloquent is slow when I have hundreds of records with the relationships

Comment: no Eloquent is not slow u have to use  with for eager  loading

Comment: aight I will try to eager load first